# visual studio 2015 c++ add a standalone dll file to a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, dllimport

So I'm working on some libraries for c++ to make a beginner's experience easier. I've put the libraries into a standalone dll and now i want to add it to another project. But the thing is after searching the internet for ages, i have to have include directories and stuff but all i want is to include the single dll file to the project so the project can access the .h and .cpp files inside. Ik i can just add external jar with java then i can access the libraries in there but how do i do it with c++ in visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how C++ works (I also assume you're not talking about C++/CX or MC++ - which strictly speaking are *not* C++)

The C++ language does not define an "Application Binary Interface" - an ABI, which allows linking between binaries. That's an implementation concern.

There *are* ABIs that support C++, such as COM and CORBA, indeed the latest one is WinRT - itself based on COM.

C++ differs from languages like Java and C# which mandate a runtime which does have an ABI: Java has its `.class` and `.jar` files while .NET/C# has its CLR Metadata contained within its assembly (`.dll` files - which are not the same thing as "real" DLL files).

Note that DLL files generated by the C# compiler are nothing like DLL files generated by your C/C++ compiler toolchain's linker - while they share a common outer format as PE (Portable Executable) files, internally they are radically different: CLR DLLs contain CIL, an intermediate bytecode, whereas "real" DLLs contain native, processor-specific instructions.

The general way to work with other libraries in C++ is to either use them in source-form (as `.c` and `.cpp` files included in your project), or as `.h` header files with `.lib` (static libraries) which are almost similar to reusable binaries, except they're linked ("compiled into- and merged-with") into your finished binary and cannot be replaced at runtime.

The other way is with Dynamic Linking which requires your runtime (i.e. Win32) to do the runtime linking for you, usually with `GetProcAddress` - but this only exports C-style functions, not entire objects and classes (and certainly not any C++ templates).

In summary:

- You have a DLL and you want to use code inside of it:

  - Is it a WinRT DLL?

    - If you want to use pure C++ then you need to use WTL. [Beware, this approach is not for the faint-hearted](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/using-c-and-com-with-winrt/240168150).
    - Else, if you're okay with C++/CX then you can actually use the "Add Reference" UI in Visual Studio, but be advised, you're no-longer writing "real" C++ anymore.
  - Else is it a COM library?

    - (Note that you will need the ATL (Active Template Library) and the IDL definitions of the types contained within, this is the COM equivalent of a header file). You can also use `#import` and/or use the IDE to generate the actual `.h` and `.c` files needed to call COM without too much pain. However you will run into problems if you replace the COM DLL later without rebuilding your program if too many things were changed in a later COM DLL version (see "DLL Hell").
  - Else is it a traditional native Win32 PE DLL?

    - All a PE executable has is a list of exported functions and their address locations within the DLL.
    - Do you want Static Linking or Dynamic Linking?

      - For Dynamic Linking, do you want runtime resolution (painful, but flexible) or "automatic" linking?

        - For runtime linking you only need the `.dll` file and `.h` files. You will need to manually call `GetProcAddress` yourself for each function you want to call, then invoke it. An advantage is that you can detect at runtime if a function exists and gracefully handle linking errors.
        - For automatic linking you will be given a `.lib` file in addition to the `.dll` and `.h` files, the `.lib` file is a small statically-linked library that contains stubs and other code needed to perform the runtime linking for you without needing to manually call `GetProcAddress` yourself.
      - For Static Linking you won't have a `.dll` file, but a `.lib` file: known as a "static library". Inside it's a file that contains discretised executable function blobs which your linker will effectively copy+paste into your completed program.

Answer (score 0):

How do you do it like Java? Well, you don't.

A header is required to provide the compiler with the prototypes of the functions and other symbols that are exported from the DLL that you might want to make use of. You may even have multiple header files to logically divide your DLL's code. And since you won't want to hard-code the path to these header files in your source code, you'll want to specify the path to its containing directory as part of your compiler/build options, freeing you to use relative paths.

A LIB file is generally also required, although this is slightly more flexible. Generally, a LIB makes things much easier. It will be generated by the linker when you compile the DLL, and it contains stubs that facilitate linking to functions exported by that DLL. You specify this LIB file in your linker options when building an application that uses the DLL, and things just work. This is called *implicit* dynamic linking. It's dynamic linking because you're using a DLL, but it's implicit because the linker is handling the dirty work for you.

If you don't want to use a LIB file, you will need to do *explicit* dynamic linking. This is still dynamic linking because you're still using the DLL, but it's explicit because you have to explicitly write code to load the DLL module and obtain pointers to functions that it exports. Microsoft's build tools provide various features to make this easier, but it's still more difficult than just using the LIB file, which is what I would recommend unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.